# search for all variations of a package name with python

Tags: python

given a package name, i want to search known websites to see if that package exists.  the problem is, some packages have capitalized letters, titled letters, small case letters and so on.

for instance, suppose i have a package called:  lp-Solve-1.0.tar.gz

and generally, i can find this package on a site like this:

`https://www.example.com/packages/l/lp-Solve/lp-Solve-1.0.tar.gz`

other times, the website(s) may have the package named with a different case letter:

`https://www.example.com/packages/L/lp-solve/lp-solve-1.0.tar.gz`

or like this:

`https://www.example.com/packages/L/LP-SOLVE/LP-SOLVE-1.0.tar.gz`

As you can see here, there are many different ways the package can be named on a website.

I have no clue where to begin with this.

I was using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
listOfWebsites = [ website1, website2, website3, website4, and so on ]
goodWebsites = []
for eachWebsite in listOfWebsites:
    genURL = eachWebsite + "/" + packageName
    res = requests.head(genUrl)
    if res.ok:
         goodWebsites.append(genURL)
```

but where Im stuck at is how to search the websites for all the possible names a package could be called.

Comment: If you're attempting to check every single uppercase/lowercase possibility (i.e. brute force), you'll be banned by the servers due to a potential DoS threat much before you obtain the package you're looking for. If you can't have a reproducible pattern to check against, I'd suggest you to rethink the goals of your project.

Comment: If you have some control with the server, or if it is a "cooperative" one, you might have the option of listing the files under a path (as, for example, Linux APT package mirrors usually do, like [this](http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/)). Or if you can use FTP instead of HTTP that should also make things easier. But as the previous comment said trying every possible combination of lower- and upper-case letters is not likely to work; maybe you could have a few different possibilities for each package (e.g. lower-case, upper-case, title-case), but that's all.